# HTTrack for android! or something similar to that

Tags: android

I would like to know if anything software, plugin or app is available similar to HTTrack!

Comment: I think NO, but what you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to download some website content and want to be available offline on android.  I googled it but dint found much thing related to android so right now I am trying/ guessing that running a terminal code on android similar to HTTrack can solve my problem! but i am afraid of those root permission. so if anythying is available which I am not aware of please try to share it.

Answer (score 3):

An alpha release of **HTTrack** is available for ([Android](http://android.httrack.com/)), but a stable version will take some time :)

Answer (score 0):

[HtmlUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HtmlUnit) [works](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) on Android, you can use to to crawl and save pages.

---

Or you can modif[y this application](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/App/skylight1/com.wsl.marketconsolescraper.logic.htm), (it scrapes the Android Market)

---

Or if you are loading the web page ...

[saveWebArchive()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#saveWebArchive%28java.lang.String%29%29)